# accessing python list or Dictionary inside a string

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python I am trying to access a field which is in string format in a CSV file which has a list of dictionaries.

one row of `train['list_of_production_companies']`

```
"[{'name': 'Lions Gate Films', 'id': 35}, {'name': 'Vertigo Entertainment', 'id': 829}, {'name': 'Gotham Group', 'id': 3672}, {'name': 'Tailor Made', 'id': 24557}, {'name': 'Mango Farms', 'id': 24558}, {'name': 'Quick Six Entertainment', 'id': 24561}]"

train['list_of_production_companies'] = train['production_companies'].apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x]  if i[name] != {} else [])
```

---

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 train['list_of_production_companies'] = train['production_companies'].apply(lambda x: [i.name for i in x]  if
>   i.name != {} else [])
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
>   apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    3190
>   else:    3191                 values = self.astype(object).values
>   -> 3192                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    3193     3194         if len(mapped) and
>   isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in (x)
>   ----> 1 train['list_of_production_companies'] = train['production_companies'].apply(lambda x: [i.name for i in x]  if
>   i.name != {} else [])
>
> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: is this part of a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Your comprehension is incorrect in the lambda function.

Use:

```
train['list_of_production_companies'] = train['production_companies'].apply(lambda x: [i['name'] if 'name' in i else [] for i in x])
```

Comment: `i['name']` in  the if condition as well

Comment: Yes. Just saw that.